# Cross-Domain issue in Chrome possibly b/c of strange Dart HttpRequest behavior

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, amazon-s3, dart, cors

I know guys, there are tons of questions about the `Amazon S3` Buckets and `CORS`. But please, let me add mine.

So I'm writing an application in `Dart` and I am performing an ajax request to a resource which is hosted on S3. I originally wanted to grab the first 100 bytes of the resource which is why I came up with the following beautiful piece of code:

```
   HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
   req.open('GET', item.get('upload').get('url'));
   req.setRequestHeader('Range', 'bytes=0-99');
   req.onReadyStateChange.where((e) => req.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE).first.then((e) {
      print(req.responseText);
   });
   req.send();
```

As you may guess from the title of this question, this code didn't work and I get a

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

This seemed pretty strange to me, since I set up a `CORS` which should prevent this issue...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

For whatever reasons this obviously doesn't work. I loaded the application in Firefox and voila, it's working. It seems like `CORS` does work and the issue is either because of `Chrome` or `Dart`.

I fiddled around a little bit and for some reasons, you may excuse me, it's pretty late here, I came up with this:

```
   HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
   req.open('GET', item.get('upload').get('url'));
   req.setRequestHeader('Range', '0-99');
   req.onReadyStateChange.where((e) => req.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE).first.then((e) {
      print(req.responseText);
   });
   req.send();
```

Yea exactly, I just removed `bytes=` from my previous code snipped. And guess what, suddenly my ajax requests runs through and prints the full text. Wooot?! I can add a corrupted `Range Header` and I get over this security issue? Well, that's exactly what just happend. Of course, I got more than the first 100 bytes, but at least I got something. Since I had no explaination why a corrupted `Range` header make the request work, I replaced the `Range` header with some other random strings and none of them worked.

I know, your mind probably just got blown - so did mine! Thus I want to summarize what we just discovered.

- Making a Cross-Domain ajax request in Chrome with Dart doesn't work due to security issues, although
- the CORS which is setup seems to work at least for Firefox.
- Chrome's security issue can be 'exploited' by adding a corrupted `Range` request header, but
- no other header has the same effect.

Like really? I mean, I have no idea whats going on here. 
Can anyone explain at least something to me? - and in case someone has an idea or solution to address the issue that I cannot get the first 100 bytes in Chrome, I would be thankful for the rest of my life.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds weird. CORS is not a programming language issue, it's a browser/server issue. Have you tried it with both, Chrome and Dartium? Any difference? Can you investigate in the browsers DevTools what the response looks like?

Comment: The response itself is empty. These are the response headers: http://pastebin.com/euzrG8uN

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I also just made the discovery that when I move the request to the main_app.dart such that it's the first statement which gets executed, everything works fine.

Comment: What happens in between (app-start to the location of the request?). Where is the request made from normally?

Comment: The application consists of more than 70 self written Polymer elements and uses tons of Core and Paper ones. It's pretty massiv and there happens quiete a lot between the start and the point where the request is made. The request is normally made from an`attached()` callback in a custom Polymer element. However, the main_app is also a custom Polymer element. Thus I do not think the problem is Polymer related. At this time, I have absolutely no idea how to continue debugging this issue.

Comment: How does the URL exactly look like? Are they 100% equal in both cases? Can you check in the browser dev-tools?

Comment: I hardcoded the URL and it works when using the code in the main_app element but not in my other custom one.

Comment: Is it an absolute or relative URL?

Comment: Absolute URL. - Code: http://pastebin.com/5tw6yuhX (I replaced the URL of the image)

Comment: The request doesn't have a port but the error message has `8080` is this a copy/paste error?

Comment: The request doesn't have a port. The error message says that the origin `localhost:8080` is not allowed. I am sending the request from `localhost:8080` and not making a request to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to fix the bug.

No, it's neither a Chrome nor a Dart bug. It has something todo with some cache. The solution is a dirty string query hack which is simple to do:

```
   HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
   req.open('GET', '${item.get('upload').get('url')}?t=${new Random().nextInt(99999)}');
   req.setRequestHeader('Range', '0-99');
   req.onReadyStateChange.where((e) => req.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE).first.then((e) {
      print(req.responseText);
   });
   req.send();
```

Adding a random number to the query will cause the cache, I don't know if it's the Amazon or Chrome cache, to do the correct thing.